# How to calculate slope and linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, anova, ancova

After creating the plot using:

```
plot(Mother_weight_mg~Clutch_size, pch=21, bg=c("Lightblue","orange"),las=1,xlab="Clutch Size",ylab="Mother Weight")
abline(lm(Mother_weight_mg~Clutch_size)[which(History=="Fresh carcass")],col="lightblue",lwd=5)
abline(lm(Mother_weight_mg~Clutch_size)[which(History=="Old carcass")],col="orange",lwd=5)
```

We are then told to use this ANOVA:

```
Ancova_1 <- aov(Mother_weight_mg~History*Clutch_size)
> Ancova_1
Call:
   aov(formula = Mother_weight_mg ~ History * Clutch_size)

Terms:
                 History Clutch_size History:Clutch_size Residuals
Sum of Squares    962.22    12314.91               68.45  70187.69
Deg. of Freedom        1           1                   1        53

Residual standard error: 36.39088
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
> summary(Ancova_1)
                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
History              1    962     962   0.727 0.39783   
Clutch_size          1  12315   12315   9.299 0.00357 **
History:Clutch_size  1     68      68   0.052 0.82103   
Residuals           53  70188    1324                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

All of this came out normally but then to get the intercepts we are told to use `lm()`. So I did that:

```
> summary.lm(Ancova_1)

Call:
aov(formula = Mother_weight_mg ~ History * Clutch_size)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-80.986 -20.864  -1.333  23.217  71.217 

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    201.3818    19.1180  10.534 1.32e-14 ***
HistoryOld carcass               2.3931    24.1567   0.099   0.9215    
Clutch_size                      1.3563     0.6164   2.200   0.0322 *  
HistoryOld carcass:Clutch_size  -0.1878     0.8263  -0.227   0.8210    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 36.39 on 53 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1598,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1122 
F-statistic: 3.359 on 3 and 53 DF,  p-value: 0.02543
```

But it only gave me information about "old carcass" and not "fresh carcass". What do I need to do differently to get both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your "carcass" variable is here, but I think I can still answer your question. The reason you are likely confused is because the factors in a regression (the categorical variable like "carcass") is dummy coded into a regression to create a **reference group** and **comparison groups**. The reference group is represented by the intercept, which is the conditional mean of the response variable (in this case "mother weight") for new carcass. The coefficient for old carcass is the adjustment to this conditional mean, in other words adding/subtracting the intercept and slope here give you the conditional mean of the new carcass factor. Your other slopes (like "clutch size") are simply additional adjustments to the conditional mean.

As an example using the `iris` data in R, we know that the petal lengths of the flower species from the data is easily found with this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Mean.Petal = mean(Petal.Length))
```

Giving us our mean petal lengths:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    Mean.Petal
  <fct>           <dbl>
1 setosa           1.46
2 versicolor       4.26
3 virginica        5.55
```

If we fit that to a regression using no other predictors other than species, we will get identical estimates:

```
fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Species,
          iris)
summary(fit)
```

See below.

```
Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-1.260 -0.258  0.038  0.240  1.348 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        1.46200    0.06086   24.02   <2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor  2.79800    0.08607   32.51   <2e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica   4.09000    0.08607   47.52   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4303 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9414,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9406 
F-statistic:  1180 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Setosa is used as the reference group, so the intercept is $1.46$, the mean of this species. The slopes are the additions to make up the means of the other groups. For example, if we add up the intercept and the first slope, we get the mean of the Versicolor plant species:

$$
\text{Petal Length} = 1.462 + 2.798 = 4.26
$$

Entering other slope terms simply adjusts the mean after conditioning for the other predictors. For example the below fit adds the main effect of petal width, the main effect of species, and the interaction between the two:

```
fit2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Species * Petal.Width,
           iris)
summary(fit2)
```

Showing the coefficients below:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species * Petal.Width, data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.84099 -0.19343 -0.03686  0.16314  1.17065 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     1.3276     0.1309  10.139  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor               0.4537     0.3737   1.214   0.2267    
Speciesvirginica                2.9131     0.4060   7.175 3.53e-11 ***
Petal.Width                     0.5465     0.4900   1.115   0.2666    
Speciesversicolor:Petal.Width   1.3228     0.5552   2.382   0.0185 *  
Speciesvirginica:Petal.Width    0.1008     0.5248   0.192   0.8480    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3615 on 144 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9595,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9581 
F-statistic: 681.9 on 5 and 144 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

We can see now that the estimates are now slightly different for the intercept and species terms. This is because they are conditional as we mentioned before. The only difference now though is that the main effect of petal width is now included, and the interactions between the factor variable and petal width are also added. The slopes for the interactions indicate what the slope should increase or decrease by each factor, which is visualized below in the plot:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Width,
             y=Petal.Length,
             color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(
    method = 'lm',
    se=F
  )+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  labs(x="Petal Width",
       y="Petal Length",
       title = "By-Species Petal Dimensions")
```

[image]

We can see that setosa, the reference group/intercept term, has the lowest slope, and this slope is determined by the main slope term of petal width. The other slopes by species are incremental increases in slope based off the coefficients. Versicolor's interaction term is the highest because the magnitude increases the most of all the species ($\beta = 1.3228$).

Comment: I think your answer misses the most important point, which is that the OP's model has an interaction and therefore they cannot meaningfully interpret the main effect on its own.

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer, hopefully providing clarity.